# FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen is not triggered... I use last version of firebase_messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1) and firebase messaging:  11.2.4,
trying to use FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen for backgorund mode but this method in my case does not register any changes, also tested the code from the example, but it didn't work even then.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @Josteve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70846755/firebasemessaging-onmessageopenedapp-listen-method-from-firebase-messaging-last

Answer (score 1):

Use `onMessageOpenedApp` only when the application is in the background, not foreground or terminated.

> A Stream event will be sent if the app has opened from a background
> state (not terminated).

See [onMessageOpenedApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html) for details.

To handle click your push notification in foreground & background, you can try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74780154/13184236).