# FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen method from firebase_messaging (last version) not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first function where  I get backgound messsage and everything work's fine.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
   options: const FirebaseOptions(
   /// Svi podatci uzeti iz google-services.json-a
   apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
   appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
   messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
   projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
   ),
  );
 print('Background message received!');

 var decoded = NotificationModelPusherAG.fromJson(message.data);
 var encodedMessage = json.decode(decoded.message);
 var decodedMessage = PusherMessage.fromJson(encodedMessage);

 FirebaseNotifications.showNotification(
 decodedMessage.title, decodedMessage.description);
}
```

Here is my main method  and here also everything works fine :

```
Future<void> main() async {

 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 final String INSTANCE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

 await PusherBeams.start(INSTANCE_ID);

 await Firebase.initializeApp(
 options: const FirebaseOptions(
  /// Svi podatci uzeti iz google-services.json-a
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxx',
),
);

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In init state I get message but FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen is not triggered.

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();

 FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .getInitialMessage()
    .then((RemoteMessage message) {
  if (message != null) {
    print('eeeeeeeej');
  }
});

 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  var decoded = NotificationModelPusherAG.fromJson(message.data);
  var encodedMessage = json.decode(decoded.message);
  var decodedMessage = PusherMessage.fromJson(encodedMessage);
  print(decoded.creatorId);
  print(decodedMessage.description);

  // AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
  if (message.data != null) {
    FirebaseNotifications.showNotification(
        decodedMessage.title, decodedMessage.description);
  }
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Heeeeey');
  if (message.data['type'] == 'malfunction') {
    print ('aaaa');
  }
  if (message.data['type'] == 'notice') {
    print ('bbbbbbb');
  }
  if (message.data['type'] == 'poll') {
    print ('cccccccc');
  }
});
}
```

In debug console when click on message I get nothing.

My flutter version : (Channel stable, 2.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a new file `push_notification_service.dart` and put below code as it is.

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  '0', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  importance: Importance.max,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

class PushNotificationService {
  Future initialise() async {
    await _fcm.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    String fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      _showMessage(event);
      RemoteNotification notification = event.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = event.notification?.android;
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings(
          '@mipmap/ic_launcher'); // <- default icon name is @mipmap/ic_launcher

      var initializationSettings =
          InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                icon: android?.smallIcon,
                // other properties...
              ),
            ));
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      try {
       
        if (message.data['item_type'] == 'category') {
          //Navigate to category screen
        } else if (message.data['item_type'] == 'profile') {
           // Go to profile screen
        } 
        
      } catch (e) {
        print("object-----ERROR------>$e");
      }
    });
  }

  void _showMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
   // Show your In-App messaging Dialog
  }

 
}
```

Now in your `main.dart` just replace your `initstate()` function with mine

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then(
      (value) async {
        Firebase.initializeApp().then(
          (value) {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10), () async {
                PushNotificationService().initialise();
              });
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```