# Firebase Navigator is not working on onMessageOpenedApp

Tags: flutter, message, navigator

I read all topics on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. I'm trying to use navigator when you click on the notification. Everything is working fine but when you click on it there's no error and no navigating, the notification just disappears. What can i do? I will share the code

```
 initState(){
    super.initState();
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid,);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      LocalNotificationService.display(event);
    });
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
                              Get.to(Conversa()); // I've tried to use navigator too, it not worked
                          });
  }
```

OBS: If i try to use navigator inside onMessage it works but i don't want to automatically send the user to the x page

Comment: I use `Navigator` it works fine

Comment: Is an application in the foreground while clicking a notification?

Comment: Yes, it is in foreground

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75635436/14207423

Answer (score 2):

Use `onMessageOpenedApp` only when the application is in the background, not foreground or terminated.

> A Stream event will be sent if the app has opened from a background state (not terminated).

See [onMessageOpenedApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html) for details.

Comment: Now i understand, thank you so much. What can i do to use Navigator in foreground when the notification is opened?

Comment: Use to onMessage to handle a message in the foreground. No need to show a notification, the user is already in the application, so use some other way to inform the user about a new message or if you are not worry about the user to lose the context, navigate directly from onMessage.

Answer (score 0):

For foreground & background you can set the payload in flutter_local_notification from onMessage.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

      if (notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
        String? payload = message.data;

        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            ...
            payload: payload);
      }
});
```

Then, use payload value to manage your navigate in onSelectNotification

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
     // Navigate
});
```