# FCM FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp Won't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Although all the other functions work perfectly, I receive the message and display it in all conditions, in the background, foreground or initial message.

in the background:

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
```

in the foreground:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        add(NotificationRecieved(message));
      }
    });
```

in the initialization of the application:

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        LocalNotificationService.display(message);
        return message.data["route"];
      }
    });
```

but this doesn't work: when I click on the notification

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (message) {
        toast(message.data.toString());
        var route = message.data["route"];
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
      },
    );
```

the function (onMessageOpenedApp.listen) itself isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Do Checking Like This:

---

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
     
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
   
      if (notification != null && android != null) {


-----do your action here



}
```

Comment: it didn't work, I think the function itself isn't working for some reason, I receive the message and display it, but it doesn't do the action

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null && message.data["route"] != null) {
        toast(message.data.toString());
        var route = message.data["route"];
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be helpful.
First in method to show push notification add reader of a payload.

```
void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
            // one that already exists in example app.
            icon: 'launch_background',
          ),
        ),
        // Add reading of a payload based on the contents of notification
        // In my case:
        payload: notification.data['params']);
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in the application for example in initState method try to call the payload.

```
NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails != null && notificationAppLaunchDetails.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      var payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails.notificationResponse?.payload;
      if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
        // Your code to handle the payload for routing.
      }
    }
```

Be aware that flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin is properly initialized in main().

Answer (score 0):

**onMessageOpenedApp** this will work only once your app is in background state (not terminated)

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  log('onMessageOpenedApp');
  //onTap navigation app is in background not terminated 
});
```

For foreground state you can use local notification plugin like this

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('onMessage');
      showFlutterNotification(message);
    });

    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
       const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
            AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
        const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
            InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        );
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
          initializationSettings,
          onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
              (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
            if (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType ==
                NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification) {
               //onTap navigation app is in foreground state
              // payload 
              var payload = notificationResponse.payload;
            }
          },
          onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
          null,
        );
```

Pass payload data while showing notification with local notification plugin example below

```
  void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: 'ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
        ///here passing payload
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
    }
  }
```